# Nagios Core 4.2.0 Service not running after reboot

Tags: nagios

I am running Nagios Core 4.2.0 to monitor hosts and services via Check_MK plugin. This is running on a VM. Once I rebooted, I cannot get a PID for Nagios.

```
root@hostname:/etc/init.d# service nagios status
● nagios.service - Nagios
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nagios.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-10 09:09:34 CDT; 1min 2s ago
  Process: 2369 ExecStart=/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2369 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 10 09:09:34 hostname systemd[1]: Started Nagios.
Aug 10 09:09:34 hostname systemd[1]: nagios.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 10 09:09:34 hostname systemd[1]: nagios.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 10 09:09:34 hostname systemd[1]: nagios.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is there a way to get this PID to run? I am not sure how a simple reboot can make this go bad.